# Get the Id of the element in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have assigned the id value of an element in angularjs to a variable like below

```
var test = angular.element("#sqldiv");
```

I'm sending the test variable to a function and wanted to use the id of the element in the function. I'm unable to retrieve the id value.  when I try to put an alert for test. it just give [object,Object] as the output.Please let me know how to retrieve the id value of the element. i.e I wanted the value as `"#sqldiv"`.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `test[0].id`, but please explain your usecase. Looks like you're doing stuff the nonangular-way

Comment: This looks like you are trying to do something that could be done a lot cleaner - handling elements directly is almost always the wrong thing to do in Angular. Use data binding instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
test[0].id
```

This will give you `id` of element.

Comment: Although this is correct, I strongly advise against answering this question without telling OP not to pass DOM elements around in Angular, as they seem to be new to it.

Answer (score 2):

Angular's jQlite works like jQuery with a little limitation of features to esure a good performance so that you can use jQuery's method `$.fn.attr` to do such thing.

For example:

```
var elm = angular.element(document.getElementById("#sqldiv"));

console.log(elm.attr('id'));
```

> **Note on `angular.element`:** Its selector are limited so you can't query by id like that, you have to pass the element it self to jQlite like: `angular.element(document.getElementById("#sqldiv"))` or `angular.element(document.querySelector("#sqldiv"))`
>
> **Note on using DOM with angular:** As it's been told on comments, avoid using DOM for data binding, angularjs has its own way to do that, most of activities doesn't require DOM manipulation, you should create a directive to do such thing, where you have the appropriated way to handle it.

Comment: Although this is correct, I strongly advise against answering this question without telling OP not to pass DOM elements around in Angular, as they seem to be new to it.

Comment: @LionC there is no prohibition on passing DOM elements around depending on what you are trying to do I can't tell if he's creating a component directive or just trying to display a text variable. But you're right though, I should've added a note on that, and I will. Thanks :{D

Comment: True, there are cases where its needed. But most of them are already solved by the existing structuring directives and in I'd say 95% of cases when someone newish to Angular asks about handling DOM elements, they need to be told not to do it :-)